# NodeJs request http module options.uri error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Trying to post a simple object through nodejs using `request http` module, every time I try to send my data to my API it showing this `options.uri is a required argument` yet I provided a URL end point where to `POST` the data.

```
var url = 'http://omcloud.azurewebsite.net/api/Test';
request.post(url,
            { json: { "Definition": "Test"} },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log(body)
                }
            }
        );
```

Can someone shed a light what's wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding url : url inside post's json

```
  var url = 'http://omcloud.azurewebsite.net/api/Test';
    request.post({ 
                url : url, 
                json: { "Definition": "Test"} },
                function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        console.log(body)
                    }
                }
            );
```

Comment: still the same though